# show next item title on previous next hover carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am using twitter bootstarp carousel in my web page. I need to show the title of next item on mouse over over the next arrow.

Html:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide homecarousel" data-ride="carousel">
<!-- FIRST for slide -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item active"  title="Adult">
slider 1
</div>
<div class="item"  title="Baby">
slider 2
</div>
<div class="item"  title="Ingredients">
slider 3
</div>
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev" ><img src="images/arrow_left.png" alt=""></a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next" ><img src="images/arrow_right.png" alt=""></a>

</div>
</div>
```

How to achieve this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Where do you want to show the title?

Comment: When hover over the next arrow show as arrow title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? :

```
$('.carousel-control').on('mouseover', function() {
    var titles = $('.carousel-inner .item').map(function(){ return this.title; });
    var currentIndex = $('.carousel .active').prevAll('.item').length;
    var title = titles[currentIndex + 1 > titles.length -1 ? 0 : currentIndex + 1];
    if ($(this).hasClass('left')) {
        title = titles[currentIndex - 1 < 0 ? titles.length - 1 : currentIndex - 1];
    }
    $(this).attr('title', title);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yQLZm/1/)

Comment: Thanks for you response. I tried your code. Now if i hover over the previous arrow it shows the current item title. But i need to display the previous item title.

Comment: Does your class 'active' get updated? It needs to be on the current slide. Otherwise the code will never work.

Comment: It's working. Some class conflicts caused the issue. Now your code works perfectly. Thanks for your effort.